# Any way to match on return value in C++11?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I am trying to provide a function which calls a provided lambda, and I'm wondering if it's possible to have it return a default value if the function has return type `void`.

Here's what I have so far, a function which returns the lambda's return value, but if the lambda is `void`, then it returns 20.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template <typename H>
auto f(H&& h) -> decltype(h(), void())
{
    return h();
}

template <typename H>
auto f(H&& h) -> decltype(h(), int())
{
    h();
    return 20;
}

int main()
{
    int r = f([](){ std::cout << "test1" << std::endl; return 10; }); // error here
    std::cout << "r: " << r << std::endl;
    r = f([](){ std::cout << "test2" << std::endl; });
    std::cout << "r: " << r << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This produces the error,

```
test.cpp:20:68: error: call of overloaded ‘f(main()::<lambda()>)’ is ambiguous
```

So clearly this is just due to C++ not being able to use polymorphism based on return type.  However, I am wondering if there are any good C++11 tricks, such as better use of `decltype` or some template magic, that might make this possible?  I am asking because as far as I can see there is no real ambiguity here.. the compiler is inferring the `void` return type and then saying that it's ambiguous whether to match the `int` or `void` version of `f`, which is a bit silly.

A reason for doing this is that if the function `f` expects a return value but the user provides a lambda that doesn't include a `return` statement, the compiler infers a `void` type, and errors out.  Since in the real scenario I have a good idea of what a reasonable default return value should be when the user doesn't care to provide one, I am wondering if it's possible to have the compiler allow users to neglect the often-unnecessary `return` statement for convenience.

Thanks.  I should mention that I am using GCC 4.6.3.

*Answer*: based on Xeo's suggestion of using `enable_if`, I came up with the following, which seems to work:

```
template <typename H>
auto f(H&& h) -> typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<decltype(h()), void>::value, int>::type
{
    h();
    return 20;
}

template <typename H>
auto f(H&& h) -> typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<decltype(h()), int>::value, int>::type
{
    return h();
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: have you tested f on normal functions?

Comment: Yes, on normal functions it is also ambiguous.

Comment: Second parameter of `decltype`: Can I ask what it's for? (Really, because I don't know!).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use std::enable_if.

Your return type would be `std::enable_if<!std::is_same<decltype(h()), void>::value, decltype(h())>:type` for the first one, and `std::enable_if<std::is_same<decltype(h()), void>::value, int>::type` for the second one.  That should get your code working.  I haven't tested it, so I'm not sure if it works fully.

Comment: @Steve: No, this works correctly. I think you might have a typo somewhere. See [this](http://liveworkspace.org/code/e0c94a11d120300743e202f4daec8a66).

Comment: @Xeo: Ah, thanks, I think the second `decltype(h())` in the first part of JKor's solution was problematic, as it changed the return value for `f()`.  I got it working based on your examples, I'll post the code in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Give me a reason on why the compiler should be able to infer why which overload to select based on what you do inside the function? In C++, overload resolution is only concerned if every argument is matchable to a parameter. The return type and the content of the function are of no interest *what-so-ever*.

[As STL says](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-C-/Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-Cpp-3-of-n#c634790677481084163):

> TLDR: Templates are greedy! Don't overload them unless you're absolutely sure what will happen.

And a universal reference (`template<class T> void f(T&&);`) as a parameter is the greediest you can get.

You can solve it like @JKor says with SFINAE, but simplified:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class F>
auto f(F f)
  -> decltype(true? f() : void())
{
  f();
}

template <class F>
auto f(F f) -> decltype(int(f()))
{
  f();
  return 42;
}

int main(){
  f([]{});
}
```

Note that GCC 4.7 has a bug where `decltype(int(void_returning_function()))` doesn't cause the function to SFINAE out. Clang 3.1 correctly makes

```
f([]{});
```

work, aswell as

```
f([]{ return 42; });
```